# Bypass wifi-activation-button in XP start-up on Amilo L1310g

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

Right then. I have a problem on a Fujitsu Siemens Amilo L1310g.

This (old) machine is constructed with a ("feature") physical button that **activates the wireless internet**.

- When pressed XP starts finding available networks.
- When not pressed; XP says no networks are available.

Pretty stupid, especially because this button must be pressed EVERY TIME a user logs in to his/her account.

I would like to bypass this button - and I have googled forever without finding anything useful.

So I looked into my *Task Manager* and observed what happens when I hit this button. As follows

- a.) **Cmd** starts a process
- b.) **net.exe** starts a process
- c.) **net1.exe** starts a process
- d.) within seconds all three processes disappear from *Task Manager*.

So! What I was wondering is this - **IS IT POSSIBLE TO SOMEHOW RECORD OR CAPTURE WHAT GOES ON IN THIS CMD-PROCESS??** Say, have some application running before I press this (ridiculous) button and then have a print of the cmd-process that I could copy and save in a .vbs and run at start-up. Or does this mean I have to go to Cal-Tech (Calcutta) for a couple of semesters?
Obi-Wan, where are you now?

Comment: Use Process Explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). Find out from where this cmd process starts. Make it run whenever you log in.

Comment: Is it a normal keyboard button or a Special Toggle button ?

Comment: @ Lamb: it is a Special Toggle button. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Like kgiannakakis said in their comment, [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) should be able to show you where the process starts. Use that to find what it runs and add a shortcut to it to your startup folder.

Comment: First thing; my apologies for posting at the wrong forum (stackoverflow).

Second: I used **Process Explorer** (ahead of the game :-) ) for observing what happens when I hit this wifi-button - but since the process disappears shortly after it stars (very few seconds), I have no idea of how to study the phenomenon more closely? Or how to access/read the command that seems connected with cmd and the net.exe- + net1.exe-files

Comment: UPDATE. It seems that the cmd and net(1).exe runs as a part of a program called **XPFix.exe** (after some googling, I assume this is a controller for the WLAN-unit in the computer).

I also managed to take some screendumps of the process-info (in **Process Explorer**) but it doesn't really make any sense to me. A lot of 'Directories', 'keys', and 'Mutants' are listed but I have no idea what I can do with this information. I'm still at a loss.

Comment: What does the Device Manger say the name of the wireless chip is?

Comment: @ James: It's called "Ralink RT 2500 Wireless LAN Card"